Emboss STL from SVG
I'm new to Fusion 360 (have basic experience with modeling software) and really struggling with what I thought would be a simple task.
I'm trying to remix this STL to emboss it with this SVG.
Steps I've taken:

Imported STL
Generated Faces
Converted Mess
Started Sketch on face
Imported SVG
Create -> Emboss

However, I can't figure out a sane way to actually select the  lines in the sketch during the emboss setup. I tried creating a selection set, and that didn't work.  I feel like I must be missing something fundamental.



I have added image hover tags for you. However, the image descriptions may not be correct or descriptively accurate. Could you check and maybe [edit] if necessary. Thanks.

Also, is this related to 3D printing? Are you going to print the resulting model? If not, then you might want to ask on Engineering.SE (but please don't cross post). See Where can questions that are purely about 3D modelling, or CAD, software be asked?

@Greenonline yes, I'm planning on printing it.  I guess maybe it's more of a pure CAD question, though, so point taken... Although I finally brute forced my way through the workflow and my emboss is too small for the printer resolution :)

No, no, we have a very very low bar for 3D printing related questions. You only have to mention in the question that you plan on printing it... :-) Could you post an answer to explain how you solved your issue? Thanks.

@Greenonline I'm not sure I'd say I "solved it"...  I just spent way too long manually selecting hundreds of paths with the shift key held.  I would like to leave it open in case someone actually knows
